# Database - Soft-delete or separated log table

Tags: database, rest, api, database-design, architecture

I'm building a REST API which has the followings endpoints:

```
GET /api/v1/categories - Get all categories
DELETE /api/v1/categories/$id - Delete a specific category
```

When the client requests all categories, the server has to return all categories with the HTTP header *Last-Modified*.

Once the a category has been deleted and the client requests all categories with HTTP header *If-Modified-Since* older than the deletion time, the server shall returns all categories, without the deleted one, but with the HTTP header showing the last modified time, even if this time was the time of the deletion.

I'm thinking about in two approach to implement this:

1. Add a column with a flag indicating if it was deleted (soft-delete);
2. Create a table to record tables modifications.

In the first approach, I'll add a column in the category table that will indicate if the record has been deleted or not. In this way, with this column and the column that stores the last modification timestamp, I can check if any modifications happened after the given timestamp.

In the second approach, I'll add a table that records the last modification in any table. Each line of this table is the last modification which happened in any other table of the system. In this way, when a category is deleted, the record in the log table which holds information about category table is updated indicating that the last operation was a delete with the timestamp of the operation. In this way, when I have to check if any changes happened in the category table after a specific timestamp, first I check the log table and decide if I'll query the category table.

Even though I've used the category as the example, this problem happens to other resources of my API and the solution shall be used to them in the same way.

What do you guys think about the presented approaches to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st approach has several inconveniences

- You will store data that will never been accessed again once a more
  recent modification occurred
- if you have some constraint (eg.
  unique) on your table, you won't be able to create new records which
  collides on the "softly" deleted ones

On a more general mater, "soft" deletion is rarely a good idea and can often be solved using the [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) approach coming from domain driven design

Comment: You're right. What do you suggest for this problem? I can't find other approaches besides those I listed...

Comment: Well, the 2nd approach seems to fit your needs :)

Comment: Do you know what the best way to implement this 2nd approach? Is it using database triggers to update the log table automatically every time which a category changes?

Comment: Well the "best way" depends on your requirements, architecture and maybe tech stack. The trigger approach is simple and simplicity is a great things regarding maintainability and extensibility. If you use an event driven model, you can move the event listener from persistence (trigger) to data access or business layer, you may also use a decorator pattern on your data access layer or use AOP (or "middleware" in the node.js)... the list is not exhaustive :) I'd say that it's up to you :)

Comment: I see. My stack is Grails (Groovy, Hibernate etc.) with Postgres. The suggestion you made about event listener is good. I think that event listener in service layer is better for maintainability than a trigger in database, but I don't know about performance. Is there any impact in the performance?

Comment: There is always a performance impact :) an additional access to db has a cost, probably negligible here. The user experience may or not be impacted regarding whether or not your event is handled synchronously.... Don't bother too much about that imho. If you use hibernate you may go with entity listener, it seems suitable for your case

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how frequently and how earlier can Last-Modified go. You can use the first approach and retain the deleted categories in your table let's say for a week and add a background job to remove the categories deleted 1.5 weeks ago or so.

Comment: I thought about this too, but the background job can remove the deleted category only when there are modifications in category collection (of the user owner of the deleted category) after the deletion time. But I'm not sure if this is a good solution, because I always see people saying to avoid soft-delete...

Comment: I agree soft delete is not a good approach because it retains garbage in the table. Again it depends upon your business need. you can remove the entries from categories and add/insert it in another table using the background job or triggers.